# Creating a link for your app to be launched by other apps

Tags: ios, swift

Now I'm fully aware you can use something like this to launch instagram from another mobile application(not tested):

```
    var instagramHooks = "instagram://user?username=johndoe"
    var instagramUrl = NSURL(string: instagramHooks)
    if UIApplication.sharedApplication().canOpenURL(instagramUrl!) {  
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(instagramUrl!)
    } 
    else {
        //redirect to safari because the user doesn't have Instagram
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string: "http://instagram.com/")!)
    }
```

What I'm interested in is creating a url that takes you directly to a certain page inside the mobile application. `instagram://user?username=johndoe`
 takes a user to the profile page of `johndoe` after launching the application.  How can one go about creating a link similar to this?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to use [Compass](https://github.com/hyperoslo/Compass) to achieve this.

With compass you can do it like this

```
Navigator.handle = { [weak self] location in
  let arguments = location.arguments

  let rootController = self?.window.rootViewController as? UINavigationController

  switch location.path {
    case "profile:{username}":
      let profileController = ProfileController(title: arguments["username"])
      rootController?.pushViewController(profileController, animated: true)
    case "login:{username}":
      let loginController = LoginController(title: arguments["username"])
      rootController?.pushViewController(loginController, animated: true)
    case "logout":
      self?.clearLoginSession()
      self?.switchToLoginScreen()
    default: 
      break
  }
}
```